# Focus a textfield after its value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a form in which you select an option from a dropdown menu. When an option is selected a value is set for the textfield. What I also want to happen is that it focuses on that textfield after the value. For example: I select facebook from the drop down and "http://www.facebook.com/" appears as value of the textfield. When facebook is selected the focus also goes to the textfield after the last character of the value that is already added.

I made a JSFiddle with what i have thusfar:

http://jsfiddle.net/dgUrj/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Add the right URL prefix for social media
    $('select').change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
        if(this.value == "Facebook"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.facebook.com/");
        }
        if(this.value == "Twitter"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.twitter.com/");
        }
        if(this.value == "LinkedIn"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.linkedin.com/");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `focus()` trigger after the value is set, like so:

```
$('#social-url').val("http://www.twitter.com/").focus();
```

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
         $('#social-url').val("http://www." + this.value.toLowerCase() + ".com/")
                         .focus();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgUrj/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution! And improvement to my function in general!

Answer (score 0):

Just place this after your if statements it will automatically focus on the textbox after dropdown select happens.

```
   $('#social-url').focus();
```

so in your code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Add the right URL prefix for social media
    $('select').change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
        if(this.value == "Facebook"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.facebook.com/");
        }
        if(this.value == "Twitter"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.twitter.com/");
        }
        if(this.value == "LinkedIn"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.linkedin.com/");
        }
         $('#social-url').focus();
    });

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dgUrj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Could be simply done like this:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dgUrj/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Add the right URL prefix for social media
    $('select').change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
        if(this.value == "Facebook"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.facebook.com/");
        }
        else if(this.value == "Twitter"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.twitter.com/");
        }
        else if(this.value == "LinkedIn"){
         $('#social-url').val("http://www.linkedin.com/");
        }

        if(this.value) $('#social-url').focus();
    });

});
```